# Vagrant + CakePHP で192.168.33.10/Appにアクセスした際に画面が白くなる

Tags: cakephp, apache, vagrant

Vagrantでローカルフォルダを同期して開発環境を整えていますが、`http://192.168.33.10/App`にアクセスすると白い画面になってしまいます。

ついでに可能であれば`App`ディレクトリではなくて、`http://192.168.33.10/`をDocument Rootに設定したく、/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.confファイルを

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/App">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

に変更して試してみても白い画面になってしまいます。

ディレクトリ構造は以下の通りです。
/home/vagrant/【appName】/App

【appName】内
App  Plugin  Vagrantfile  Vendor  composer.json  composer.lock

App内
Config  Console  Controller  Lib  Model  Plugin  Test  Vendor  View  index.php  webroot

といった構造になっていて、Vagrantfile内で
`config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/hoge/Vagrant/【appName】/", "/home/vagrant/【appName】"`
で同期設定しています。

どなたか解決方法をご存知のかたご教授をいただけると幸いです。

追記：以下各バージョンになります。
Max OSX Yosemite
Vagrant 1.7.2
Box CentOS64
Apache Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
cakePHP 2.7.2

////////////
`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`に設定してあります。

Comment: まずは，エラーログを確認してください。cakephpのエラーログ`App/tmp/logs/error.log` を確認して何も出ていなければ、apacheのエラーログをみましょう。

Comment: また、ディレクトリ構成からCakePHP2.xだと思われますが、cakephp,apacheあとOSの各バージョンも記載しておくと良いでしょう。

Comment: apache側の設定で、DocumentRootの値もお願いします。

Comment: 情報不足ですみません。。。追記いたしました。

Comment: synced_folder のパーミッションの問題だったりしませんか？

Comment: @holywise さん, Vagrantfileでは`config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/hoge/Vagrant/【appName】/", "/home/vagrant/【appName】", owner: 'vagrant', group: 'apache', mount_options: ['dmode=777', 'fmode=755']` と記述後、`vagrant reload`してみたのですがやはり白い画面のままでした。

Answer (score 1):

Apache httpdのドキュメントルートがCakePHPのwebrootに設定されていないことが原因と考えられます。

apacheの設定として、

```
DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/【appName】/App/webroot

<Directory "/home/vagrant/【appName】/App/webroot">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

と設定しましょう。

また、`/home/vagrant`のパーミッションが`0700`になっていれば`0755`へ変更してください。

なお、上記はとりあえずの対策となります。
本来であれば、仮想環境でも本番環境と同一の構成とすべきですから、synced_folderの設定は

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/hoge/Vagrant/【appName】/", "/var/www/【appName】"
```

にして、DocumentRootを`/var/www/【appName】/App/webroot`にしたほうが良いでしょう。

Comment: ご回答いただきまして有難うございました。

両方のパターンを試してみたのですが、未だに白い画面のままでした。。。

Comment: CakePHPとApacheのログは確認されましたか？

Comment: @kphex ブラウザの開発者ツールを使って、まずはどのようなレスポンスが返されているのかを調査されると良いと思います。

Comment: /home/vagrant/ 以下のディレクトリは apache が読み込める権限になっていますか？

Comment: 白い画面ということはサーバー側の設定/権限エラーの可能性が高いので、apacheのエラーログ、cakephpのエラーログを確認する方が先です。

Answer (score 0):

short_open_tag が true でないのに `<?` を使ってしまっているという可能性ありますかね？ その場合、画面は真っ白ですが、ブラウザでソースを見ると、php のソースが見えたりします。

あとは、いずれかのライブラリ的な php ソースの末尾や頭に余分な空白があるとか。冒頭の `<?php` の前とか、末尾の `?>` の後とか。余分な空白があると、header 出力前に空白が body として出力されて、画面が白くなることがあったきがします。